# data being overwritten in **Result.next()** loop

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, resultset

I have a search button that goes into my database and searches on a name but when there are two entries for the same name it is only bringing me back one and i can't figure out why. Below is the code I am using now.

```
 public boolean search(String str1, String username){//search function for the access history search with two parameters
    boolean condition = true;
    String dataSourceName = "securitySystem";//setting string datasource to the securitySystem datasource
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:odbc:" + dataSourceName;//creating the database path for the connection
    try{
        //Type of connection driver used    
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

        //Connection variable or object param: dbPath, userName, password
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "", "");

        Statement statement = con.createStatement();//creating the statement which is equal to the connection statement

        if (!(username.equals(""))){
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from securitysystem.accessHistory where name = ?");//query to be executed
            ps.setString(1, username);//insert the strings into the statement
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();//execute the query
            if(rs.next()){//while the rs (ResultSet) has returned data to cycle through
                JTable table = new JTable(buildTableModel(rs));//build a JTable which is reflective of the ResultSet (rs)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));//put scrollpane on the table
        }
        else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"There has been no system logins at this time");// else- show a dialog box with a message for the user
            }
}
statement.close();//close the connection
    } catch (Exception e) {//catch error
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return condition;   
}
```

Comment: You are using an `if` instead of a `while`. Show `buildTableModel` if you are looping your resultSet

Comment: What the heck does `"buildTableModel(...)` do?? Isn't that method a bit on the critical side here?

Comment: Since you don't show `buildTableModel()` nobody could possibly help you.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how you can use a `TableModel` to add data to the table.

Assumming you have these initial model conditions

```
String[] columnNames = {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3"};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTablModel(columnNames, 0);
JTable table = new JTable(model);

...
```

You should be doing *something* like this

```
while (rs.next()){
    String s1 = rs.getString(1);
    String s2 = rs.getString(2);
    String s3 = rs.getString(3);

    Object[] row = {s1, s2, s3};

    model.addRow(row);
}
```

---

**Edit:** To get column names directly from database, you want to use `ResultSetMetaData`.

Try this method out.

```
public DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs){

    ResultSetMetaData rsMeta = rs.getMetaData();
    int cloumns = rsMeta.getColumnCount();

    String columnNames = new String[columns];
    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++){
        columnNames[i - 1] = rsMeta.getColumnName(i);
    }

    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);

    while (rs.next()){
        // Just an example retrieving data. Fill in what you need
        String s1 = rs.getString(1);
        String s2 = rs.getString(2);
        String s3 = rs.getString(3);

        Object[] row = {s1, s2, s3};

        model.addRow(row);
        // End example
    }

    return model;
}
```

Then,

```
if (rs != null){
    JTable table = new JTable(buildTableModel(rs));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code calls `rs.next()` one too many times. You call it before you call your `buildTableModel(...)` method in your search method above, essentially wasting a row of data that you never use.

Instead, just pass the ResultSet into the method without calling next on it, and then use your while loop *inside of `buildTableModel(...)`* to fill your data vector. If the vector is empty, then throw an exception, or return an TableModel with 0 rows.